# How to Calculate Statistics for Open-Ended Frequency Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

If you had a frequency distribution something like the below (and did not have the raw data), how would you calculate statistics without being able to determine the midpoint of the final range (*595+*).

I have considered taking a sample of the dataset (*0-9* to *520-594*) and approximating it as a Normal Distribution with the Central Limit Theorem, then estimating the "effective" maximum (99%) for the range. However, this seems very approximate and not a true representation.

How should I estimate the midpoint of the *595+* range in the example below for calculating statistics such as the Average, Standard Deviation, etc?

---

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
Value & \text{Occurrences} \\
\hline
0-9 & 150 \\
10-24 & 146 \\
25-44 & 211 \\
45-69 & 205 \\
70-99 & 175 \\
100-134 & 195 \\
135-174 & 435 \\
175-219 & 369 \\
220-269 & 279 \\
270-324 & 210 \\
325-384 & 144 \\
385-449 & 138 \\
450-519 & 130 \\
520-594 & 97 \\
595+ & 14
\end{array}
$$

*Please note: Values are made up, and are a lot more "pretty" than they are in the actual dataset.*

Comment: You cannot compute arithmetic mean, standard deviation for open-ended classes. Instead look for other measures of central tendency and dispersion.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do you have any recommendations for what I could try?

Comment: You could try finding median,mode and quartile deviation for example.